# si adelanto mi hora local, ¿el tiempo UNIX es el mismo?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, unix, timezone

Ya sea que lo adelante horas, minutos, dias, meses ¿el UNIX es el mismo? o este ¿se adelanta junto con mi hora?.

PD: no estoy hablando de adelantar la zona horaria, porque se que el UNIX es el mismo entre zonas

Comment: Si adelantas tu hora local, el unix también se adelanta, el código new Date() o moment() toma como referencia de reloj la hora local del dispositivo. Normalmente, cuando el timestamp es crítico, se toma la referencia del reloj del servidor o de un servidor NTP que sirva de referencia temporal para todos los dispositivos.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo